# Solve sparse under-determined system

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I want to solve `Ax = b` for `x` where `A` is sparse, `b` is dense, and `x` is dense.

I am not sure if `A` is positive-definite. A has the following form:

```
* * * 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 * * * 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 * * *
* 0 0 * 0 0 * 0 0
0 * 0 0 * 0 0 * 0
0 0 * 0 0 * 0 0 *  where * represent a positive number.
```

Which solver should I use?

More than 90% of each row is zero.

I don't really care about accuracy a lot because this is part of a coordinated  ascent for a non-linear system of equations.

It should use multiple threads.

Thanks.

Comment: How large are your matrices in practice? If they are as tiny as in the example, then better use a dense matrix with a dense solver, like `PartialPivLU`. Otherwise, try the different solvers and see for yourself. Changing from one solver to another is a one-line change in Eigen.

Comment: About 50,000 x 50,000. Each row has about 90% zeros.

Comment: Do you always have the structure of three `1xN` blocks and three `NxN` diagonals?

Comment: Yes. Always same number of blocks, which is not three. Three is just an example. Each equation corresponds to either a weighted sum of a row or weighted sum of a column of a `NxN` array of variables. The matrix for the linear system of equations is `2N` rows with `NxN` columns. The weights (`*`) are all positive. `N` is always known and remain the same.